# Module object is not callable (kerastuner)

Tags: python-3.x, keras, module, keras-tuner

I am trying to optimize my keras NN using kerastuner but for some reason its giving me a 'module' object is not callable error on the tuner=randomsearch line.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from keras_tuner.tuners import randomsearch
from keras_tuner.engine import hyperparameters
import time

LOG_DIR = f"{int(time.time())}"

def build_model(hp):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(hp.Int("input_units", min_value=1, max_value=105, step=1), input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
    
    for i in range(hp.Int("n_layers", 1, 5)):
        model.add(Dense(hp.Int(f"conv_{i}_units", min_value=1, max_value=105, step=1), activation='relu'))
    
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
    
tuner = randomsearch(build_model, objective = "val_accuracy", max_trials = 1, executions_per_trial = 1, directory = LOG_DIR)
tuner.search(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=146, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I imported the wrong randomsearch and hyperparameters.